# Synonimize [speech-recognition] and [speech-to-text]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

[speech-recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/speech-recognition) and [speech-to-text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/speech-to-text) look like synonyms to me. The tag wiki of [speech-recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/speech-recognition) says:

> Speech recognition is the technology that is used to convert spoken words to text.

And the tag wiki of [speech-to-text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/speech-to-text) says:

> The translation of spoken words into text. Possible synonyms include automatic speech recognition, ASR, computer speech recognition, speech to text, STT.

The tag wikis actually say that they are possible synonyms, and the kind of questions is also the same and some questions are tagged both [speech-recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/speech-recognition) and [speech-to-text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/speech-to-text).

Can these tags be made synonyms?

Comment: I would expect speech recognition to be more about the general concepts, wider then just to text. I don't think those are synonyms but in that case the tag wiki needs an update

Comment: @rene I've been working on speech recognition for years... and to me it's a valid synonym.

Comment: @Cœur if you write an answer with your arguments I'm sure this can be reconsidered.